# How do I get the value in this object?

Tags: php

I feel silly for asking, but how do I get `plan` value in this object? `_object` is protected, so PHP telling me I cannot. I am using the PHP library for Recurly.

```
object(Recurly_SubscriptionList)#47 (7) {
  ["_etag":"Recurly_Pager":private]=> NULL
  ["_position":"Recurly_Pager":private]=>int(0)
  ["_count":"Recurly_Pager":private]=>NULL
  ["_objects":protected]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> object(Recurly_Subscription)#50 (6) {
      ["_values":protected]=> array(11) {
        ["subscription_add_ons"]=> array(0) {}
        ["account"]=> object(Recurly_Stub)#54 (4) {
          ["objectType"]=> string(7) "account"
          ["_href":protected]=> string(37) "https://api.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1"
          ["_client":protected]=>NULL
          ["_links":protected]=>array(0) {}
        }
        ["plan"]=> hello
```

Comment: Is there a function in the  API which returns individual subscriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since I come from a Java background, I was expecting a `getVar()` function. It turns out that PHP's Magic Method `__get()` allows me to just access it normally IF you overload your `__get()` properly.

So in specific to this case, for whoever that may stumble on to this, if you are using the Recurly PHP Library, you have to use `foreach` to get to the objects and then just access `plan` normally.

For example,
Let's say the object above was the value of the variable `$subscriptions`:

```
foreach($subscriptions as $subscription) {
      echo $subscription->plan;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There has to be some sort of object method that returns the data to you. Read the class documentation.

Comment: `__get` - Seriously magical. I read through source and found it.